# OSX: Stop autocorrect splitting words

Tags: macos, autocorrect

I am a programmer, and often I have words in all lowercase, not seperated by a space or hyphen.

In some *situations OSX will sometimes change `infoclass` to `info class` for instance

*context aware I'm sure

This feature has breached my annoyance ceiling. Is there anyway to turn it off?

I enjoy autocorrect, just not the word splitting feature.

Answer (score 3):

Navigate to **System Preferences > Keyboard > Text > Correct Spelling Automatically** (uncheck)

If you wish to leave autocorrect on, but create certain exceptions, you can alternatively leave it checked and in the same pane add, for example:

Replace: `infoclass` 
With: `infoclass`

This sets up an exclusion of sorts so that autocorrect does not change it to `info class`

Comment: Thanks, I enjoy autocorrect, just not the word splitting feature.